# How to make Nested Style in InDesign for price numbers

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to make Character Style and Nested Style in InDesign for price Paragraph Style, to format prices, but the prices will need to look like this: 3.840**99** or 890**99** where the **99** (cents) are in superscript. For example, I paste numbers in the layout that are not formatted, select the numbers and choose price Paragraph Style and then the last two numbers go superscript, no matter how much numbers there are.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a GREP style. See the image below for the solution and how it applies to some blank text. You need a Paragraph style for your body text and a Character style for the 99 cents in superscript. Feel free to format the styles as you please, i made the Character style in pink to highlight this. The essential part here is the GREP string you need to use to select the final 2 digits of each number (see 'To Text' field below).

[image]

Comment: It works on exact numbers, but when I added for example one more, look what happened http://oi64.tinypic.com/29eqfeo.jpg

Comment: Try this string instead \d{2}\s - it basicly 'reads' any 2 digits followed by a space.